# Was the oldest Chinese calendar a solar calendar?

Tags: calendar

Recently I read the English Wikipedia article about the [Chinese calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar). Surprisingly, the article stated that the oldest Chinese calendar was a solar calendar (or solar calendars).

> The traditional Chinese calendar was developed between 771 and 476 BC, during the [Spring and Autumn period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) of the Eastern Zhou dynasty. Before the [Zhou dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty), solar calendars were used.

However, as far as I know, the oldest Chinese calendar was a lunisolar calendar, which was recorded in the [oracle bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone) of the [Shang Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty). Since then, the traditional Chinese calendar continued the tradition of the lunisolar calendar. Am I wrong?

* Below is a list of early Chinese dynasties.

[Xia dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xia_dynasty)(legendary) → [Shang(Yin) dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) → [Zhou dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty) → [Spring and Autumn period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) → [Warring States period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period) → [Qin dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) → [Han dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty) → .......